# Rufus cron scheduling not working on a jetty server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jetty, cron, jruby, rufus-scheduler

*Steps to replicate:*

1. Create a new Rails project. (rails 3.2.22.5)
2. Add dependencies (warbler, rake, rufus-scheduler) (/Gemfile)
3. JRuby 9.1.7.0
4. Create new files. (/config/warble.rb) (/web.xml.erb) (/config/intializers/scheduler_rufus.rb)
5. Create an executable war file with jetty webserver. (warble war RAILS_ENV=development)
6. Launch the executable. (java -jar mywar.war)
7. The scheduler does not run the cron job.

/Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.22.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'

gem 'jruby-openssl'

gem 'warbler'

gem 'rake', '11.3.0'

gem 'rufus-scheduler', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.3'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyrhino'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

/config/warble.rb

```
# Disable Rake-environment-task framework detection by uncommenting/setting to false
# Warbler.framework_detection = false

# Warbler web application assembly configuration file
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  # Features: additional options controlling how the jar is built.
  # Currently the following features are supported:
  # - *gemjar*: package the gem repository in a jar file in WEB-INF/lib
  # - *executable*: embed a web server and make the war executable
  # - *runnable*: allows to run bin scripts e.g. `java -jar my.war -S rake -T`
  # - *compiled*: compile .rb files to .class files
  config.features = %w(executable)

  # Application directories to be included in the webapp.
  config.dirs = %w(app config db lib log script vendor tmp)

  # Additional files/directories to include, above those in config.dirs
  config.includes = FileList["web.xml.erb"]

  # Additional files/directories to exclude
  # config.excludes = FileList["lib/tasks/*"]

  # Additional Java .jar files to include.  Note that if .jar files are placed
  # in lib (and not otherwise excluded) then they need not be mentioned here.
  # JRuby and JRuby-Rack are pre-loaded in this list.  Be sure to include your
  # own versions if you directly set the value
  # config.java_libs += FileList["lib/java/*.jar"]

  # Loose Java classes and miscellaneous files to be included.
  # config.java_classes = FileList["target/classes/**.*"]

  # One or more pathmaps defining how the java classes should be copied into
  # the archive. The example pathmap below accompanies the java_classes
  # configuration above. See http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/String.html#M000017
  # for details of how to specify a pathmap.
  # config.pathmaps.java_classes << "%{target/classes/,}p"

  # Bundler support is built-in. If Warbler finds a Gemfile in the
  # project directory, it will be used to collect the gems to bundle
  # in your application. If you wish to explicitly disable this
  # functionality, uncomment here.
  # config.bundler = false

  # An array of Bundler groups to avoid including in the war file.
  # Defaults to ["development", "test", "assets"].
  # config.bundle_without = []

  # Other gems to be included. If you don't use Bundler or a gemspec
  # file, you need to tell Warbler which gems your application needs
  # so that they can be packaged in the archive.
  # For Rails applications, the Rails gems are included by default
  # unless the vendor/rails directory is present.
  # config.gems += ["activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", "jruby-openssl"]
  # config.gems << "tzinfo"

  # Uncomment this if you don't want to package rails gem.
  # config.gems -= ["rails"]

  # The most recent versions of gems are used.
  # You can specify versions of gems by using a hash assignment:
  # config.gems["rails"] = "4.2.5"

  # You can also use regexps or Gem::Dependency objects for flexibility or
  # finer-grained control.
  # config.gems << /^sinatra-/
  # config.gems << Gem::Dependency.new("sinatra", "= 1.4.7")

  # Include gem dependencies not mentioned specifically. Default is
  # true, uncomment to turn off.
  # config.gem_dependencies = false

  # Array of regular expressions matching relative paths in gems to be
  # excluded from the war. Defaults to empty, but you can set it like
  # below, which excludes test files.
  # config.gem_excludes = [/^(test|spec)\//]

  # Pathmaps for controlling how application files are copied into the archive
  # config.pathmaps.application = ["WEB-INF/%p"]

  # Name of the archive (without the extension). Defaults to the basename
  # of the project directory.
  config.jar_name = "mywar"

  # File extension for the archive. Defaults to either 'jar' or 'war'.
  config.jar_extension = "war"

  # Destionation for the created archive. Defaults to project's root directory.
  # config.autodeploy_dir = "dist/"

  # Name of the MANIFEST.MF template for the war file. Defaults to a simple
  # MANIFEST.MF that contains the version of Warbler used to create the war file.
  # config.manifest_file = "config/MANIFEST.MF"

  # When using the 'compiled' feature and specified, only these Ruby
  # files will be compiled. Default is to compile all \.rb files in
  # the application.
  # config.compiled_ruby_files = FileList['app/**/*.rb']

  # Determines if ruby files in supporting gems will be compiled.
  # Ignored unless compile feature is used.
  # config.compile_gems = false

  # When set it specify the bytecode version for compiled class files
  # config.bytecode_version = "1.6"

  # When set to true, Warbler will override the value of ENV['GEM_HOME'] even it
  # has already been set. When set to false it will use any existing value of
  # GEM_HOME if it is set.
  # config.override_gem_home = true

  # Allows for specifing custom executables
  # config.executable = ["rake", "bin/rake"]

  # Sets default (prefixed) parameters for the executables
  # config.executable_params = "do:something"

  # If set to true, moves jar files into WEB-INF/lib. Prior to version 1.4.2 of Warbler this was done
  # by default. But since 1.4.2 this config defaults to false. It may need to be set to true for
  # web servers that do not explode the WAR file.
  # Alternatively, this option can be set to a regular expression, which will
  # act as a jar selector -- only jar files that match the pattern will be
  # included in the archive.
  # config.move_jars_to_webinf_lib = false

  # === War files only below here ===

  # Embedded webserver to use with the 'executable' feature. Currently supported
  # webservers are:
  # - *jetty* - Embedded Jetty from Eclipse
  config.webserver = 'jetty'

  # Path to the pre-bundled gem directory inside the war file. Default
  # is 'WEB-INF/gems'. Specify path if gems are already bundled
  # before running Warbler. This also sets 'gem.path' inside web.xml.
  # config.gem_path = "WEB-INF/vendor/bundler_gems"

  # Files for WEB-INF directory (next to web.xml). This contains
  # web.xml by default. If there is an .erb-File it will be processed
  # with webxml-config. You may want to exclude this file via
  # config.excludes.
  # config.webinf_files += FileList["jboss-web.xml"]

  # Files to be included in the root of the webapp.  Note that files in public
  # will have the leading 'public/' part of the path stripped during staging.
  # config.public_html = FileList["public/**/*", "doc/**/*"]

  # Pathmaps for controlling how public HTML files are copied into the .war
  # config.pathmaps.public_html = ["%{public/,}p"]

  # Value of RAILS_ENV for the webapp -- default as shown below
  config.webxml.rails.env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'

  # Public ROOT mapping, by default assets are copied into .war ROOT directory.
  # config.public.root = ''

  # Application booter to use, either :rack or :rails (autodetected by default)
  # config.webxml.booter = :rails

  # When using the :rack booter, "Rackup" script to use.
  # - For 'rackup.path', the value points to the location of the rackup
  # script in the web archive file. You need to make sure this file
  # gets included in the war, possibly by adding it to config.includes
  # or config.webinf_files above.
  # - For 'rackup', the rackup script you provide as an inline string
  #   is simply embedded in web.xml.
  # The script is evaluated in a Rack::Builder to load the application.
  # Examples:
  # config.webxml.rackup.path = 'WEB-INF/hello.ru'
  # config.webxml.rackup = %{require './lib/demo'; run Rack::Adapter::Camping.new(Demo)}
  # config.webxml.rackup = require 'cgi' && CGI::escapeHTML(File.read("config.ru"))

  # Control the pool of Rails runtimes. Leaving unspecified means
  # the pool will grow as needed to service requests. It is recommended
  # that you fix these values when running a production server!
  # If you're using threadsafe! mode, you probably don't want to set these values,
  # since 1 runtime(default for threadsafe mode) will be enough.
  config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 1
  config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 1

  # JNDI data source name
  # config.webxml.jndi = 'jdbc/rails'
end
```

/web.xml.erb

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
  <!--
  <display-name>Uncomment and put name :here: for Tomcat Dashboard</display-name>-->

  <%# NOTE: to be renamed to servlet_context_params %>
  <%- webxml.context_params.each do |name, value| -%>
  <context-param>
    <param-name><%= name %></param-name>
    <param-value><%= value %></param-value>
  </context-param>
  <%- end -%>

  <%- if webxml.respond_to?(:servlet_filter) -%>
  <filter>
    <filter-name><%= webxml.servlet_filter_name %></filter-name>
    <filter-class><%= webxml.servlet_filter %></filter-class>
    <async-supported><%= !! webxml.servlet_filter_async %></async-supported>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name><%= webxml.servlet_filter_name %></filter-name>
    <url-pattern><%= webxml.servlet_filter_url_pattern %></url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <%- else -%> <%# NOTE: due compatibility when warbler gets downgraded to 2.0.0 %>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jruby.rack.RackFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <%- end -%>

  <%- if webxml.respond_to?(:servlet_context_listeners) -%>
  <%- webxml.servlet_context_listeners.each do |listener| -%>
  <listener>
    <listener-class><%= listener %></listener-class>
  </listener>
  <%- end -%>
  <%- else -%> <%# NOTE: due compatibility when warbler gets downgraded to 2.0.0 %>
  <listener>
    <listener-class><%= webxml.servlet_context_listener %></listener-class>
  </listener>
  <%- end -%>

  <%- [webxml.jndi].flatten.each do |jndi| -%>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name><%= jndi %></res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
  <%- end if webxml.jndi -%>
</web-app>
```

/config/initializers/scheduler_rufus.rb

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton

unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake'
  # only schedule when not running from the Ruby on Rails console
  # or from a rake task

  scheduler.cron '15 18 * * *' do
        puts 'Hello World'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saying "it's not scheduling". I guess you've waited until the specified `1815` but nothing happened.

According to your previous question ([Why is Rufus scheduling the job twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119327/why-is-rufus-scheduling-the-job-twice)) rufus-scheduler is actually scheduling, so what's happening?

Rufus-scheduler 3.3.3 (the one you seem to be using) defaults to using Rails' timezone. This timezone is set in config/application.rb and defaults to UTC.

Could it be that you waited until 1815 local time (not UTC time) and nothing happened?

Try with a schedule like `"* * * * *"` (every minute) or `"*/5 * * * *"` (0, 5, 10, 15, ... minute).

Comment: You are a god. Awesome reply. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm not a god. Kudos to you on the pro issue reporting.

Comment: You guys seem nice.

Answer (score 1):

@jmettraux nailed it.

/config/application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

/config/initializers/scheduler_rufus.rb

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton

unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake'
  # only schedule when not running from the Ruby on Rails console
  # or from a rake task

  scheduler.every '10s' do
      puts Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  end

  scheduler.cron '52 19 * * *' do
      puts 'Hello World'
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: This is not working time is getting print, but the message hello world is  not getting print.